# Obj-c wont parse if statement with mod

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, modulo

So Im using a simple if statement to increase an object's speed when an score is reached. Im using a very simple if statement that doesnt work. In this context, "pigSpeed" controls the velocity of the object.

```
    float difference = (self.view.bounds.size.height/4) - flyingPig.center.x; 

    score += -(int)difference;

    if (score % 1000 == 0 & score > 0)
    {
        pigSpeed++;
        NSLog(@"pigfaster");
    }
```

I know the score works properly, as it is displayed, as it appears, but the if statement just wont work and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong. I can add more code if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is the bitwise and operator; `&&` is the logical and that you mean to use here. Your if statement should actually read:

```
if (score % 1000 == 0 && score > 0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Be more specific about the behavior—"it crashed on the if statement", "the if statement was never true", etc.

Comment: The && operator didnt change anything. But I managed to solve it anyway, I had to give just a bit of leeway so

'if (score % 1000 == 2 && score > 999)'

Answer (score 1):

Further to what @victor ronin said...

```
float difference = ( self.view.bounds.size.height / 4.0f ) - flyingPig.center.x; 

int newScore = score + difference ;
if ( newScore > 0 && ( newScore / 1000 > score / 1000 ) )
{
    // did thousands place increment?
    ++pigSpeed;
}

score = newScore ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with andyvn22 - you should use && instead of &. However, there is one more problem.

Let's say you have score = 999

after you calculate difference and it's difference = -5

Your score will become 1004. 1004 % 1000 will be 4 (not a zero)

I think you should change your condition some way that even if you jump over 1000 you still increase a speed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to give just a bit of leeway so 'if (score % 1000 == 2 && score > 999)'